# SQL Server Query to Get Available Employee based on Schedule

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two tables, parent table `Employees` and child table `Employees_Availability`, like this:

`Employees` table:

```
EmployeesID   Name     Group    Availability_Order  Available
--------------------------------------------------------------
     1        Steve    Sales            1           TRUE
     2        Ann      Sales            2           TRUE
     3        Jack     Sales            3           FALSE
     4        Sandy    Support          4           TRUE
     5        Bill     Support          5           TRUE
     6        John     Support          6           TRUE
```

`Employees_Schedule` table:

```
EmployeesID    Day             From     To  
----------------------------------------------
     1         Monday           8:00    12:00   
     1         Monday          13:00    17:00   
     2         Monday          12:00    13:00   
     3         Tuesday          7:30    11:30   
     3         Wednesday        7:30    11:30   
     3         Friday          14:30    16:30   
     4         Tuesday         11:30    17:00   
     5         Wednesday        8:00    12:00   
     5         Wednesday       13:00    17:00   
     5         Thursday        12:00    13:00   
     5         Friday           7:30    11:30   
     6         Friday          12:00    13:00
```

How can I create a query that given date/time and Group return first available employee? I am using SQL Server 2012. Here is what I started doing but got stuck:

```
Select top 1 
    Name 
from 
    Empolyees e join? Employees_Schedule s 
on
    e.employeesID = s.EmployeesID 
where
    e.group = 'Sales' 
    and DATENAME(Weekday,'5/24/2016 10:00') = s.Day 
    and CAST('5/24/2016 10:00' AS TIME) 'hh:mm' >= CAST(s.from AS TIME)
    and CAST('5/24/2016 10:00' AS TIME) 'hh:mm' <= CAST(s.to AS TIME)
order by 
    e.availability_order
```

Thanks

Comment: How is the time stored in `from` and `to`? Are those varchars? Also, why stick `'5/24/2016 10:00'` into this? Why not just `WHERE s.day = 'Monday' AND s.from < '10:00' AND s.to > '10:00'? Will that `'5/24/2016 10:00'` come into this from a variable or something?

Comment: yes, from and to are varchar. the date is just an example that I can substitute in the query as needed or use getdate()

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: Thanks marc_s. I will edit.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into Window Function and CTE?  You could easily achieve this with, for example..

```
Row_Number() OVER(PARTITION BY day ORDER BY starttime ASC) as ColumnName
```

Combined with predicate

`WHERE columnName = 1 AND groupName = 'groupname'`

For detail, read BOL on OVER()Clause [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189461.aspx), and CTE [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're close.  If you wrap the main part of your SQL in a [Common Table Expression](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) and use the [row_number() window function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) then you can find the first available:

```
;with cte as (
 Select top 1 
     Name,
     row_number() over (order by ea.From) PrioritySequence
 from 
     Empolyees e join? Employees_Schedule s 
 on
     e.employeesID = s.EmployeesID 
 where
     e.group = 'Sales' 
     and DATENAME(Weekday,'5/24/2016 10:00') = s.Day 
     and CAST('5/24/2016 10:00' AS TIME) 'hh:mm' >= CAST(s.from AS TIME)
     and CAST('5/24/2016 10:00' AS TIME) 'hh:mm' <= CAST(s.to AS TIME)
)
select *
  from cte
 where PrioritySequence = 1
```